# Application Insights - How do i set the Operation.Id to a GUID with dashes

Tags: azure-application-insights

I need to set the ApplicationInsights operation.Id to a GUID, including the dashes.  This is part of an existing system and we need the operaitonID to work with our existing correaltionIDs which have this format. This seems to work if I remove the dashes from the GUID, but it does not work with the full 36 character GUID or with some hard-code strings I have tested.

Using the code below I see the operation.id is set to the guid just before the using statement.  However, once the operation is started (in the using line) the Operation.Id changes to an arbitrary value.

```
var telemetryRequest = new RequestTelemetry();
telemetryRequest.Context.Operation.Id = "402152e3-5273-4c37-b439-7d84de6bceb5";
using (var operation = _telemetryClient.StartOperation(telemetryRequest))
{
}
```

If I remove the dashes from my guid, making it a 32 character string, it seems to work and the operation.id does not change when the operaiton starts.  I tried a 32 characters string of numbers (all 4s) and it also works, but if I use all letters it will not work.

According to the documentaion, operation.id is a string.  I don't see any special requirements or rules.

How can I use my existing correlation IDs as the operation.id in application insights?

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://dzimchuk.net/event-correlation-in-application-insights/)

Comment: That helped a little.  I'll update the post.